# Unable to manage a purchased domain through azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I bought a domain through azure portal but i can't find any file manage option for my domain and there is no option to manage mail account. I want to know if there is any portal like CPANEL or something similar for domain managing?

Comment: Even if you purchase a domain from the Azure Portal, I seem to read that the domain is hosted by GoDaddy, which would mean you would probably manage the domain there instead.  See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/) and [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-azure-networking/suggestions/4996615-azure-should-be-its-own-domain-registrar).

Comment: Riddhesh Sanghvi thank you and can you please tell me how i can sign in to go-daddy for managing my domain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cPanel like hosting admin in Microsoft Azure Web Apps.

cPanel is a hosting platform used by shared hosting providers such as GoDaddy or HostGator. Microsoft Azure is a cloud hosting platform in which you manage your cloud as if it where your server. You have to manually go in and setup your web apps, virtual machines etc.

If you want to use cPanel you could always spin up a Linux VM and then install cPanel on it. This will give you full control like with the other providers.

Hope this helps. Feel free to reach out to me with any questions!

Comment: Joe thanks for your answer but i want to know how to run my website standalone with out connecting my domain with azure domain. here is my domain that i have purchased http://harunabad.net/. but it is not up because my azure domain is down http://haroonabad.azurewebsites.net/. So tell me how to handle it.